# Vue: "_" prefixed property not working in data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to set a computed property as prop to a child component in Vue.js.

This is an excerpt of the component code ([Here's the full (not) working example](https://codepen.io/mikekastner/pen/XWWoRZv)):

```html
<div id="app">
  <show-me :title="aTitle"></show-me>
</div>
```

```js
const ShowMe = {
  data() {
    return {
      _title: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    title: {
      set: function(val) {
        this._title = val;
      },
      get: function() {
        return this._title;
      }    
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      should display title: {{title}} <br/>
      but instead typeof title: {{typeof title}}
    </div>`
};

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    aTitle: 'A Title'
  },
  components: {
    'show-me': ShowMe
  }
});
```

When running the example the component's title value in the template is undefined. It's pretty simple and straightforward and I don't get it why it's not working.

Comment: It looks like your component should only need to define a `title` prop (ie `props: ['title']`). You do not need the `_title` data property or your `title` computed property

Comment: As to why using a computed property: it's an excerpt from taken from a larger context, which would simply complicate the example.

Regarding the reporducible example: Is the codepen link not working, which I included in my question? Here, it is again: https://codepen.io/mikekastner/pen/XWWoRZv

Comment: In this case, your simplification goes too far. As it stands, your use of a computed property does not make sense. And yes, your link works but questions should contain all the required information. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I sincerely apologize for having posted my question in such a sloppy and unthoughtful way. It was by no means intended to be oversimplified nor was it intended to not make sense. I am really sorry and I wish I could undo my mistake. Since this is not possible, all that's left for me to do is to try to formulate better questions in the future and ask for forgiveness.

Comment: No need to apologize and I'm glad you found a suitable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> _ prefixed properties are reserved for Vue's internal properties. They are not available for direct binding (but you can bind to them as
> $data._message) -  Evan You (Vue creator)

You can't use `_` prefixed values cuz it get treated as internal properties in vue system

Reference  - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2098

Most proper explanation available at Docs too -

> Properties that start with _ or $ will not be proxied on the Vue
> instance because they may conflict with Vue’s internal properties and
> API methods. You will have to access them as vm.$data._property

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

So In your case you will do replace `this._title` with `this.$data._title`

```
const ShowMe = {
  data() {
    return {
      _title: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    title: {
      set: function(val) {
        this.$data._title = val;
      },
      get: function() {
        return this.$data._title;
      }    
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      should display title: {{title}} <br/>
      but instead typeof title: {{typeof title}}
    </div>`
};

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    aTitle: 'A Title'
  },
  components: {
    'show-me': ShowMe
  }
});
```

Comment: There's no `props` defined on your component so how is the `:title="aTitle"` binding supposed to work?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the the problem. I've changed the example accordingly, however it is still not working (link to codepen):
https://codepen.io/mikekastner/pen/RwwEgQY
Now I am getting: TypeError: "this.$data is undefined"

Comment: @LongHike your `data` function needs to return an object

Comment: Correct - You updated snippet does not contains `_title` in your data property

Comment: @SatyamPathak yes, you're right, of course. However, still getting "TypeError: "this.$data is undefined""

Comment: @SatyamPathak Awesome, my fault again, I messed up the data object. Thanks, this was really helpful.

Comment: @LongHike - I just saw your snippet - `data` is a function it should return

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const ShowMe = {
      props:{
        title:{
          type:String,
          required:true
        }
      },
      template: `
        <div>
          should display title: {{title}} <br/>
          but instead typeof title: {{typeof title}}
        </div>`
    };
```

or you can use simply as follows

```
const ShowMe = {
          props:['title'],
          template: `
            <div>
              should display title: {{title}} <br/>
              but instead typeof title: {{typeof title}}
            </div>`
        };
```

Comment: You can't change the OP's structure of implementation. Probably `setters` or `getters` are there for some reason

Comment: @SatyamPathak until OP gives a good reason why they need a computed property, this is the correct answer

Comment: @Phil - Probably but I was more biased on why the given snippet not working. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 1):

This code works. It will be more consistent practice to avoid using `this.$data`, though the other answer is correct in that you can certainly use it. It is better to avoid the underscores altogether and find a better naming convention. The naming in this example also isn't best practice.

```
const ShowMe = {
  data() {
    return {
      cTitle: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    title: {
      set: function(val) {
        this.cTitle = val;
      },
      get: function() {
        return this.cTitle;
      }    
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      should display title: {{title}} <br/>
      but instead typeof title: {{typeof title}}
    </div>`
};

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    aTitle: 'A Title'
  },
  components: {
    'show-me': ShowMe
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will allow you to initialize the initial value and then reactively change the dataTitle field inside the ShowMe component.

If you want to change a property from an external component, then you should do without the dataTitle field and use only props.

```
const ShowMe = {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      dataTitle: this.title
    }
  },

  template: `
    <div>
      should display title: {{dataTitle}} <br/>
      but instead typeof title: {{typeof dataTitle}}
    </div>`
};
```

You may also need the ability to change the property both inside ShowMe and from an external component. Then you can use the following code:

JS

```
const ShowMe = {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      dataTitle: this.title
    }
  },

  watch: {
    title (newValue, oldValue) {
       if (newValue !== oldValue) {
         this.dataTitle = newValue;
       }
    },

    dataTitle (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        this.$emit('changeTitle', newValue);
      }
    }
  },

  template: `
    <div>
      should display title: {{dataTitle}} <br/>
      but instead typeof title: {{typeof dataTitle}}
    </div>`
};

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    aTitle: 'A Title'
  },
  components: {
    'show-me': ShowMe
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <show-me :title="aTitle" @changeTitle="aTitle = $event"></show-me>
</div>
```